# How to make Outlook Express display non-ASCII characters correctly in message list?

Tags: windows-xp, outlook-express

Does anyone know how to make non-ASCII characters display correctly in the list of messages in Outlook Express? They are rendered correctly in the subject and message body, but not in the main window.

I set the font to Unicode in Outlook Express, but it doesn't help. I also have the appropriate language packs installed in Windows XP.

Thanks!

[image: Characters don't display correctly in preview mode]